# Linux, selenium : traffic usage starts action

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a selenium script in python and i want to do this (pseudo code)

```
open www.example.com
while traffic usage hasn't been 0 during the last 3 seconds:
        wait 3 seconds
print "everything is loaded"
```

Selenium does that very well but only with the basic elements of the page (it doesn't wait for the flash for example)
Anyway I want my script to stay on the page as long as something is loading.
The best would be to monitor only the traffic of the page but i can assume nothing else is using the network on my computer.

I see three ways of doing that :

- Using selenium to monitor the traffic but as said from my experience and my research i don't think it's possible
- Using some script to monitor traffic (iftop,ntop) to get the traffic usage, grep it and then do a condition on it
- Capture the traffic with Tshark/Tcpdump, analyse the output (the file's size): if the file size as change it means there is traffic. (it's possible but not nice at all...)

None of the solution works or suits completely my needs, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can route your traffic thru a proxy. Take look at [Browsermob](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) , at least the java bindings have `waitForNetworkTrafficToStop` method.